# Dev, Test and QA instances of SuccessFactors - 1 instance of Developer DocuSign. Whats the a good way to configure?

Tags: docusignapi, sap-successfactors

Dev, Test and QA instances of SuccessFactors - 1 instance of Developer DocuSign. Whats the best way to configure?
Within our landscape we have Dev, Test and QA (Pre-Prod) instances of SuccessFactors. DocuSign is used in the RCM and Onboarding Modules within SuccessFactors.

What i am just trying to determine is whether I have aligned and configured the Developer DocuSign instance in the best way.

With a "Generic Account" with Administrator rights in one DocuSign Development instance, i would login with those credentials and i would then take the USER ID and API ACCOUNT ID keys and use them in the configuration of SuccessFactors. I would use the same USER ID and API ACCOUNT ID in all 3 instances of Dev, Test and QA.

I did not want multiple Developer instances of DocuSign. Is this the best way?

Presently we have 1 instance of DocuSign, connecting to multiple SF instances.

Answer (score 0):

So, I would assume (not 100% sure as it depends on how you do testing) that when you test you don't want to use envelopes for real and pay for these envelopes, which means you don't want to use the production (account.docusign.com) but the [developer](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/account/) (account-d.docusign.com) environment.

The IK (clientId, Integration Key) will be the same everywhere (assuming of course you already passed [Go-Live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/) for your app)

The RSA key, userId (I assume you're using JWT) will be different in prod vs. developer account.

So, in your prod you use DocuSign prod account configuration

In your test and QA - you use DocuSign developer account configuration.

This way you can test from QA and send as many envelopes as you want and you shouldn't have any issues related to testing.